# Want to send JWT token in headers along with data using axios but getting this error : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, mern

// Generator Function for user-login-authentication 
function* addExpense(data){

```
console.log(data)
const ItemName = data.name;
const ItemAmount = data.amount;
const ItemCategory = data.category;
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
try {
    const payload1 = yield call(axios.post,'/routes/api/expenses/add-expense',{
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify({ItemName,ItemAmount,ItemCategory})
        },{
        headers:{
            'auth-token':token,
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }           
    })
```

Comment: Sounds like the error is in the response from the server, and it sounds like it is sending a response body before setting the headers.

Comment: I guess the headers is out of the object that it should be. I mean it should be like {method: ..., body: ..., headers, ...}, but what you do is : {method: ..., body: ...}, { headers: ...}

Comment: I have tried this like {method: ..., body: ..., headers, ...} but at the server side header comes inside body like body :{headers:{},body:{name,amount,category} like this , but i don't want header inside body object rather headers object...

Answer (score 0):

@Nikhil if are you using the redux-saga?  If you are using that then you did not need to use Axios you can do that with fetch or with a call directly easily. Here is a reference I hope it helps you.

```
export function* apicall(data){
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
   const header ={
     Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
      'auth-token':token,
   }
   const options = {
       method,
       mode: 'cors',
       header: header
       body: JSON.stringify({ItemName,ItemAmount,ItemCategory}),
  };

try{
    const payload1 = yield call(URL,options);
    yield[
           yield put(action,payload1),
           notification and etc facality
         ]
    }catch(error){
         yield put(action,error), 
    }
}
```

or you can also make separate util for request the API call with the header option that you need.

And the same goes for the fetch method. To give a proper answer I need more details of your code part especially API calling part so I can give you a more proper answer.